# Interfacing with transistors

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog, bjt

I was reading the chapter of [*The Art of Electronics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521809266) about bipolar transistors (chapter 2), and I came across this paragraph:

> A good understanding of transistors is very important, even if most of your circuits are made from ICs, because you need to understand the input and output properties of the IC in order to connect it to the rest of your circuit and to the outside world. In addition, **the transistor is the single most powerful resource for interfacing**, whether between ICs and other circuitry or between one subcircuit and another. Finally, there are frequent (some might say too frequent) situations in which the right IC just doesn’t exist, and you have to rely on discrete transistor circuitry to do the job. As you will see, transistors have an excitement all their own. Learning how they work can be great fun.

<sup>(Page 71, Third Edition)</sup>

But why should I use transistors, specifically, for interfacing? Why not op-amps? Are FET transistors also good for interfacing?

Could you give concrete examples (circuits) using transistors for interfacing?

Comment: read the whole sentence .... `interfacing` -- connecting one circuit to another circuit ..... connecting a digital output to a solenoid .... connecting a sensor to a digital input ...

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But why should I use transistors, specifically? Why not op-amps?

Comment: you use whatever works for you ... it could even be relays ........ read the paragraph that you posted

Comment: Its a fair question. The text may read quite vague to someone who is working to understand how it all fits together.

Comment: Powerful because you can do almost anything with transistors, including building a custom op amp (if nothing exists that meets your needs). Maybe?

Comment: The fundamentals of a transistor are useful for linear and switch mode functions which are useful in so many ways to learn before IC’s so the trade offs can be understood.

Comment: It is important to understand that IC's are made for the benefit of IC manufacturers. Not customers. They have to be apparently useful enough to customers to get bought. But like novel pharmaceuticals, the customer is not the beneficiary. "The latest IC" is often not the cheapest or even best solution - just a profitable one for the seller. A BC847, at way less than 1 cent in volume, has no marketing department pushing you to use it. Like Aspririn.

Comment: In bulk, BJT's are less than 1 US penny each. If you can do something with one or two transistors, that will usually be the cheapest and best way to do it.

Comment: @mkeith I buy them at about 0.3 to 0.4 cents each. Usually in lots of about 20k (10 boxes of 2000 apiece, for a total of about $60-$80.) Dirt cheap. I give them away by the dozens to students interested in playing. I've not yet found a source for mosfets anywhere close to that pricing, though. Sadly.

Comment: Yes. I think cheap mosfets are available from Taiwan vendors, but nothing on digikey or similar is all that cheap.

Comment: @mkeith I'll keep looking. But I've not found any chinese or taiwan supplier that can get anywhere close, yet. Maybe in millions? Don't know. So far, I'm finding them about 10X BJT prices, *at best.* I've mostly given up on small-signal mosfets for that reason.

Comment: I remember seeing power mosfets in sot-23 for only around 3 cents some odd years ago. I assumed that signal-types would be even cheaper. But I have never actually seen anything less than 3cents. Maybe it doesn't exist.

Comment: @mkeith 3 cents would be as low (or perhaps slightly lower) as anything I've seen. And that's 10X more than BJTs I can readily find. So BJTs it is.

Comment: @jonk 0.6 cent for a generic 2N7002 is doable in a Chinese market.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Would I need to travel there? Or is this available through mail order? I'll look again, I suppose. But I'd spent some time already, looking. No luck yet. But I can try again, I suppose.

Comment: Datapoint only: IC's are "just" collections of transistors.

Answer (score 4):

Using discrete transistors has benefits:

- They are cheap - basic ones are well below 1c in volume.
- They have high voltage ratings. A $1 IC today is often 5V rated, and a 1C transistor can switch 80V
- They have high current ratings. A 1c transistor can drive 1/2 an amp. A $1 transistor can drive 50amps. Your micro/opamp/whatever can drive 20mA.
- They are really really small in SOT963 packages, and come in ones.
- The heat making part of the circuit can be put in away from the rest of the circuit
- They can be inherently more robust, since they are quite a big lump of silicon, not a few micrometers in the corner of a chip
- They are in stock. If you have been in manufacturing for a while, you will suffer PTLD (Post Traumatic Leadtime Depression), a known IC condition leading to acute hair loss.
- They are good enough, and good enough is enough

Comment: Just to add: (1) They are the exact opposite of *boutique* and are often widely multi-sourced. (2) While they last, you can get BJTs used for horizontal flyback (old TV) circuits that can handle HUGE voltages and HUGE rates of change of voltage that NO IC comes anywhere close to achieving. (Sadly, I'm pretty sure that is going away forever, never to be had again.) Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Jonk give us a part number...

Comment: In general, just look up "horizontal output transistor." (Aka "HOT".) The turn-off time is critical because of the heat generated, otherwise. But these are in general high voltage BJTs (1500-2000V is typical.) Their construction is interesting, varying from "comb" and "stripe" to a variety of "mesh" types. The fastest ones I've personally used (replaced, I mean) were inside a Tektronix monitor that supported a 200MHz pixel rate, long time back.

Answer (score 1):

> why should I use transistors, specifically, for interfacing? Why not op-amps?

You should use transistors because they are useful.    So are op-amps,
use those too.   One can NOT achieve optimum results without 
considering all the options.

So, learn how to use bipolar transistors: they are the basis for
op-amps, after all.   They are also the basis for gates, latches, timers, SCRs, thermometers, photosensors, etc.

Interfacing is always a mixed-up task, where rules of input are
different from rules of output, and where solutions fall
outside the well-understood common functions that an IC catalog
will support.    A knowledge of transistors fills many gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like an amplifier, to run on

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFlhD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

0.6 volts and 100 nanoAmps, to provide gain of TWO.

[simulates: 154nA, VG=1.2; VG=2@178nA,R1=2.7M,BC547C. (H.C.)]

Comment: Next you'll be trying to tell me its cheap too

Comment: Some years back I thought thru an entire "class" of below 0.6 volt VDD transistor circuits. That 1nanoAmp Idd suggests the Vbe is 0.6v(for 1mA) - 6decades * 0.058v = 0.252 volts, is a wonderful idea.

Comment: I'd expect ~ unity gain but be surprised if it was more than 1.5

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Come on Tony, run the simulator, then give him crap about it. BTW, I am assuming its something a bit hotter than a 2n3904. What transistor is it ASR?

Comment: G=1.2, Beer for Tony...

Comment: I prefer single malt, nice try

Comment: Does the Early Voltage kill the forward gain? or what?